# How to Disable input text on form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I want to disable and enable input text **if action add input text enable** And **if action edit input text disable**

thanks

Comment: Can we see some code ?

Comment: i'm not yet code... i don't understand how to enable and disable input text if action add and edit

Comment: What is an 'action' ?

Comment: for example condition : if value == null {enable} or if value == not null {disable}

Comment: value is a javscript or a php variable ?

Comment: value = the content in input text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the jQuery function [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) :

**Javscript**

```
var value = $('input').val();

if (value == null) {
   $("input").prop('disabled', false);
} else {
   $("input").prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Here is a demo: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5032/)

Comment: value = the content in input text

Comment: so value = $('input').val();

Comment: Ok, when do you want to disable your input ?

Comment: content in the input text empty = disable

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5036/  , when the input is empty, the input = disable, that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any snippet, I tried to replicate it witll following codes.

**HTML**

```
<input type = "text" id ="demoI">
<input type = "button" value = "Add" id = "_add">
<input type = "button" value = "Edit" id = "_edit">
```

**JS**

```
window.onload=function(){
var _getInput=document.getElementById("demoI");
var _getAdd = document.getElementById("_add");
var _getEdit = document.getElementById("_edit");
_getAdd.addEventListener('click',function(event){
_getInput.disabled = true;
})
_getEdit.addEventListener('click',function(event){
_getInput.disabled = false;
})

}
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/7uk7epq9/)

Comment: thank for the answer , but in my project i need enable and disable input text on form add and form edit

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your view.

```
if( $this->uri->segment(3) == 'add' ) {
   <input type="text" name="myfield" disabled />
} else {
  <input type="text" name="myfield" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
you can do this with java script only, there is no need to use jQuery

```js
window.onload = function(){
  
   var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
   if(fname == '')
   {
       document.getElementById("fname").disabled = false;
   }
   else 
   {
       document.getElementById("fname").disabled = true;
   }
}
```

```html
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" >
```

Comment: [CHECK THIS FIIDDLE ALSO](https://jsfiddle.net/Leh3v7o6/) for edit and disabled inputs

Comment: Try this code, there is no need to use jquery to get the value and disable the input, that's simply done by java script..